building generic property selector / setter in C# if you only know the type at runtime
I'm working with API that want expressions as parameters to identitfy/modify properties on an object. This works fine if I know the type at compile Time. E.g. the APi requires an Expression<Func<T, object>>
and I can use it using an expression like x => x.Id
But, in a generic world, I have an object obj to work with and I know the name of the property. How do I build the express Expression<Func<T, object>>?
Likewise, the API I'm dealing with also needs an expression to set a given property on an object to a given value.
The API looks like this and it's an instance method:
void Patch<T, TProperty>(string id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> fieldPath, TProperty value)

when I know T and how the object looks like, I can
class MyClass { internal string Id {get; set;} }
Patch<MyClass, string>("some_id", x => x.Id, "someValue");

(with the generic definition of Patch being
Patch<T, TProperty>("some_id", x => x.Id, someValue);

where x is of T and someValue is of TProperty)
But, if I don't know T and TProperty at compile time (but can determine them at runtime), I need to formulate the proper expression.
Given the APIs I'm working with, I cannot use PropertyInfo.GetValue/SetValue (for which I do have a solution)

Can you show the implementation of Patch? How does it use fieldPath to set the property? Also, do you know T and TProperty at runtime? i.e. can you get a Type object representing those types?

I updated the question with a fully working Patch sample and clarified that I do know the types at runtime (or rather can determine them which boils down to the same)

What you ask is almost the same as EF Core's ExecuteUpdate. Notice that it doesn't use a raw  x => x.Id expression, it uses  setters => setters.SetProperty(b => b.IsVisible, false), an expresion where the compiler does know what the property is. setters itself doesn't execute anything, it's used to allow the construction of expressions

You can check the ExecuteUpdate source code and the SetPropertyCalls code in Github.

Just for clarity, for anyone developing a solution, is the Patch method static or is an instance one? To what type or actual object does it belong?

Patch is an instance method of an object that's part of the third party SDK. I'll update the question accordingly.

@PanagiotisKanavos you indeed hit the mark - I started with EfCore's ExecuteUpdate where I build a nice extension method with a lot of help. But I'm not that familiar with expressions so I was having a hard time bringing things together.

If you are always accessing .Id then you could define that all your classes implement the same interface.

@JeremyLakeman that I've already done, but Id is just the key, normally I'd patch any other attributes that are not shared. Think of it as a REST PUT that only contains the properties you want to modify - these props are different for every request (and the request could be on a variety of controllers serving different objects). That's basically my use case.

First of all:
You state the method signature is void Patch<T, U>(string id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> fieldPath, TProperty value), where T and TProperty are the meaningfull parameters, but U is an unreferenced parameter: I assume that U should be TProperty.
Now, what I think you need is an extension method to call the Patch method specifying the target PropertyInfo or specifying its name along with the declaring type.
These two alternatives are the minimum to build the expected Expression<T, TProperty>.
Take a look at the following code:
Probable original class definition (assuming the described Patch method comes from an interface):
public interface IPatcher
{
    void Patch<T, TProperty>(string id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> fieldPath, TProperty value);
}
public class PatcherClass : IPatcher
{
    public void Patch<T, TProperty>(string id, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> fieldPath, TProperty value)
    {
    }
}

Extension class
public static partial class IPatcherExtensions
{
    // Represents a callback to a convenient compiled method
    private delegate void PatchCallback(IPatcher self, string id, object? value);

    // Creates an instance of PatchCallback
    private static PatchCallback CreatePatchCallback(PropertyInfo info)
    {
        var parSelf = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IPatcher), "self");
        var parId = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "id");
        var parValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

        var parTarget = Expression.Parameter(info.DeclaringType, "target");
        var exprGetter = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(info.DeclaringType, info.PropertyType), Expression.Property(parTarget, info), parTarget);

        var exprValue = Expression.Convert(parValue, info.PropertyType);
        var body = Expression.Call(parSelf, nameof(IPatcher.Patch), new Type[] { info.DeclaringType, info.PropertyType }, parId, exprGetter, exprValue);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<PatchCallback>(body, parSelf, parId, parValue);

        return lambda.Compile();
    }

    // Caches PatchCallback instances for specific PropertyInfos
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<PropertyInfo, PatchCallback> CacheForPropertyInfo = new();
    public static void Patch(this IPatcher self, string id, PropertyInfo info, object? value)
    {
        var callback = CacheForPropertyInfo.GetOrAdd(info, CreatePatchCallback);
        callback(self, id, value);
    }

    // Caches PatchCallback instances for pairs of Type/property names
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<(Type TargetType, string PropertyName), PatchCallback> CacheForTypeAndPropertyName = new();
    public static void Patch(this IPatcher self, string id, Type targetType, string propertyName, object? value)
    {
        var callback = CacheForTypeAndPropertyName.GetOrAdd((targetType, propertyName), Factory);
        callback(self, id, value);
        static PatchCallback Factory((Type TargetType, string PropertyName) key)
        {
            var (targetType, propertyName) = key;
            var info = targetType.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            Debug.Assert(info is not null);
            return CreatePatchCallback(info);
        }
    }
}

Usage example:
IPatcher patcher = new PatcherClass();

// original
patcher.Patch<MyClass, string>("some_id", x => x.Id, "someValue");

// with type and property name
var declaringType = typeof(MyClass);
var propertyName = nameof(MyClass.Id);
patcher.Patch("some_id", declaringType, propertyName, "someValue");

// with property info
var propertyInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(nameof(MyClass.Id), BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
patcher.Patch("some_id", propertyInfo, "someValue");

Note that there are no sanity checks or error catching: You should implement them to intercept any invalid PropertyInfo or Type/name pairs.

You're correct, U should be TProperty. I edited the question accordingly.

If the original Patch method is static, rather than an instance method of an interface or class, the above code can be adapted by removing any reference to IPatcher objects, and in case changing the Expression.Call instruction to call the method properly (static vs instance).
